# need float values from a scraped list of strings for a basic if statement

Tags: python

I scraped some data from a website. I need to do a simple if statement with two values from the list of strings. I am totally lost. The values I need are both floats, but they are in the list as strings. This is the website url. 'http://vixcentral.com/historical/?days=30' Here is my code so far. I need the float values of the 3 most recent 'Contango 2/1' values for my if statements. Check out the website to get a better idea of what values I need.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('http://vixcentral.com/historical/?days=30')

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

data = []
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
values = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]
data.append(values)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to define a conversion function for string to float.

Also I would not use the variable `data` for your request, which you later overwrite as a list. The convention is `r = requests.get(...)`.

```
def str_to_float(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

r = requests.get('http://vixcentral.com/historical/?days=30')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

data = [[str_to_float(td.text) for td in tr.find_all('td')]
        for tr in soup.find_all('tr')]
```

Then you can loop through data, which is a list of lists, to pull out the specific values your are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I got it to work, it's probably not the cleanest code in the world though. I am currently creating a one page app for android, so I actually need to do the same thing in Java.